# Golang Sort package - Fuzzy sorting error

Tags: sorting, go, fuzzy

I tried to modify standard sorting approach and add certain randomness to sorting Less interface.
when

```
if (u[i] - u[j]) <= 0
```

or

```
if u[i] < u[j]
```

it works as expected
But

```
if (u[i] - u[j]) <= rv
```

condition produces panic after several executions

```
package main
import ( 
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "sort"
)

type FuzzySorter []float64

func (u FuzzySorter) Len() int {
    return len(u)
}
func (u FuzzySorter) Swap(i, j int) {
    u[i], u[j] = u[j], u[i]
}
func (u FuzzySorter) Less(i, j int) bool {
    pom, _ := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(int64(2)))
    rv := float64(pom.Int64())
    if (u[i] - u[j]) <= rv {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
func (u FuzzySorter) Sort() FuzzySorter {
    sort.Sort(u)
    return u
}

func main() {
    unsorted := FuzzySorter{
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        6,
        0,
        4,
        6,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        2,
        8,
        1,
        5,
        4,
        6,
        6,
        6,
        16,
        12,
        6,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        11,
        2,
        14,
        16,
        6,
        12,
        0,
        4,
        1,
        0,
        16,
        2,
        6,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        11,
        1,
        0,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        12,
        10,
        1,
        5,
        2,
        6,
        4,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        11,
        1,
        1,
        2,
        2,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        17,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,
        0,
        3,
        7,
        1,
        5,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        2,
        1,
        0,
        3,
        1,
        6,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        12,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        6,
        1,
        2,
        2,
        0,
        0,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        4,
        4,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        2,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        2,
        1,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        4,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        0,
    }
    unsorted.Sort()
    fmt.Println(unsorted)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4AxNRN4VD7

panic message

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x176ba0, 0x1040a010)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x700
main.FuzzySorter.Less(0x10456000, 0x9f, 0x9f, 0x19, 0xffffffff, 0x4, 0x1, 0xd)
    /tmp/sandbox201242525/main.go:21 +0x140
main.(*FuzzySorter).Less(0x10434140, 0x19, 0xffffffff, 0x5c, 0x1, 0x10434140)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0xc0
sort.doPivot(0xfef741b0, 0x10434140, 0x19, 0x9f, 0x7, 0x19)
    /usr/local/go/src/sort/sort.go:128 +0x280
sort.quickSort(0xfef741b0, 0x10434140, 0x19, 0x9f, 0xe, 0xfef741b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/sort/sort.go:195 +0xa0
sort.Sort(0xfef741b0, 0x10434140)
    /usr/local/go/src/sort/sort.go:229 +0x80
main.FuzzySorter.Sort(0x10456000, 0x9f, 0x9f, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1777a0)
    /tmp/sandbox201242525/main.go:29 +0xa0
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox201242525/main.go:195 +0xc0
```

Comment: The Less method must be deterministic, i.e. calling Less for the same 2 values must always produce the same result.

Comment: Fuzz the output instead of modifying the less function.

Comment: Philosophically, I completely agree.  Technically, do you mean that that will be enforced in some way?  Ie - are you saying that having a nondeterministic `Less()` will/can cause a panic?

Comment: I just port my function from perls  builtin sort to golangs builtin sort and surprised a bit. There is no official info about deterministic/nondeterministic requirements in "sort" godoc.

Comment: @BrianGerard Yes, the [code](https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go#L112) assumes that the ordering is deterministic.

Comment: @Y01rY5Ogfl: a randomized sort comparator is the incorrect way to add randomness. This introduces unintended bias (see https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html for a good visualization) and possibly (as seen here) completely unexpected behavior.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't panicking neither on my machine nor on playground. Can you present some reproducible case or your full panic message?

Comment: @Uvelichitel you need execute code several times it panics both on machine and playground , i'v added full panic message to body of initial post. If you rerun code in playground several times >3 i think, don't forget to add extra space to code in order to prevent playground caching

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand Go sort implementation it expect two negative comparisons eg. `Less(i, j)` and `Less(j, i)` both return false, which it treats as equality, but not positive. E.g `Less(i, j)` and `Less(j, i)` can't both return true. So you can easily achieve desired result logically correct and deterministic  way, just

```
if (u[i] - u[j]) < -1 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/VcKI9uzcM9

Answer (score 0):

As of Go 1.8, there is an easier way to sort a slice that does not require you to define new types. You simply create a Less (anonymous) lambda.

```
a := []int{5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}
sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i] < a[j]
})
for _, v := range a {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

This will sort in ascending order, if you want the opposite, simply write `a[i] < a[j]`